# A new statement was found but no delimiter

Tags: mysql

I was trying to run mysql query to display some records but it pop out an error tells A new statement was found but no delimiter. Below is my code:

```
SELECT rbs_contract_extension_survey c
INNER JOIN rbs_worker w ON c.worker_id = w.worker_id
SET
    c.worker_name = w.worker_name,
    c.batchno = w.batchno,
    c.passport_no = w.passport_no,
    c.company = w.company,
    c.arrival_date = w.arrival_date,
    c.plks = w.plks
WHERE c.worker_id IS NOT NULL
```

The error display on 'SET' command

Appreciate if somebody can help me. Thank you

Comment: If you want to display data from a query, then select statement is the correct one, but it has no set part.or you want to update the data in your tables, in which case you need an update. Can't tell from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you really want an *update* here, given that you are using `SET`.  Try this version:

```sql
UPDATE rbs_contract_extension_survey c
INNER JOIN rbs_worker w ON c.worker_id = w.worker_id
SET
    c.worker_name = w.worker_name,
    c.batchno = w.batchno,
    c.passport_no = w.passport_no,
    c.company = w.company,
    c.arrival_date = w.arrival_date,
    c.plks = w.plks
WHERE c.worker_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Its working now and I understand better